# How to get the column name of a value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have 3 tables:

Table1:

```
ID FrenchCity
1  Paris
2  Lille
3  Lyon
```

Table2:

```
ID IntlCity
1  Lille
2  Geneva
3  Toulouse
```

Table3:

```
ID BritishCity
1  London
2  Leeds
```

I would like to get the column name correspondent with a value.
For instance, I give a value `Lille` and SQL should return `Table1.FrenchCity Table2.IntlCity`.
As I said, I would like to get the column name of a value. So `Lille` exists in 2 tables, I would like SQL to return the `{{table name}}.{{column name}}`

How to write a query to do that?

Comment: You example is very short. Not sure what you want. Please explain more. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well, it's a fault. There're 3 tables. XD

Answer (score 2):

This work for you ?

```
 SELECT 'Table1.FrenchCity' as fieldName
 FROM Table1
 WHERE FrenchCity = 'Lille'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'Table2.IntlCity' as fieldName
 FROM Table2
 WHERE IntlCity = 'Lille'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'Table3.BritishCity' as fieldName
 FROM Table3
 WHERE BritishCity = 'Lille'
```

Then you can use `array_agg`

```
SELECT array_agg(fieldName)
FROM (
       previous union query
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

you better create one table with 3 columns:

```
ID COUNTRY  fieldName  CITY
1  France   FrenchCity Paris
2  France   FrenchCity Lille
3  France   FrenchCity Lyon
4  Intl     IntlCity   Lille
5  Intl     IntlCity   Geneva
6  Intl     IntlCity   Toulouse
```

ect.
then use query:

```
SELECT country || '.' || fieldName  
FROM three_col_table
WHERE CITY = 'Lille'
```

Comment: This is just a simple example, but in our database, we have hundreds of column.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wont to use DB metadata then you can to convert table data into the series of (column_name, column_value) pairs using `row_to_json` and `json_each_text` functions:

```
with
  -- Demo data start
  Table1(ID, FrenchCity) as (values
    (1, 'Paris'),
    (2, 'Lille'),
    (3, 'Lyon')),
  Table2(ID, IntlCity) as (values
    (1, 'Lille'),
    (2, 'Geneva'),
    (3, 'Toulouse')),
  -- Demo data end
  my_data as (
    select 'Table1' as tbl, j.*
    from Table1 as t, json_each_text(row_to_json(t.*)) as j(fld,val)
    union all
    select 'Table2' as tbl, j.*
    from Table2 as t, json_each_text(row_to_json(t.*)) as j(fld,val)
    -- ... and so on ...
  )
select *, format('%s.%s', tbl, fld) as desirede_value from my_data
where val ilike 'lille';

  tbl   |    fld     |  val  |  desirede_value   
--------+------------+-------+-------------------
 Table1 | frenchcity | Lille | Table1.frenchcity
 Table2 | intlcity   | Lille | Table2.intlcity
(2 rows)
```